# NAudio - How to Record from left or right channel only?

Tags: record, naudio

I need to record simultaneously from two sources, one connect to the left channel of my mic, the other connect to right. Possible to do that with NAudio ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will be recording from both channels at once, so the samples will arrive interleaved. Assuming you are recording in 16 bit audio, you would take two pairs of two bytes from the recorded buffer, and write one pair to one WAV file, and one to another.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075062/saving-each-wav-channel-as-a-mono-channel-wav-file-using-naudio/12149659#12149659) showing how you do this for an existing multi-channel WAV file.